# How to enqueue stylesheets?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to learn WP theme development. And at the moment I got some problems when I try to enqueue my stylesheet (id does'nt load). It is named style.css and located in my theme folder.

I have put this code in my functions.php file:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
wp_register_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

I can't understand what I am doing wrong? I have been reading the codex upside down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you put this code in the fie `functions.php` ? --- add `echo __FILE__;` on the top of the file to be sure this file is called

Comment: I am not sure if I understand? Where should I put this code? In my functions? I already got tons of code in my functions for custom post types for example. And that is loading correctly. Earlier I was loading my CSS the wrong way (directly in the header) and that did work. When I now change to use enqueue it does'nt

Comment: do you have `wp_head()` in the head tag of your `header.php` file?

Comment: no, I dont! Will fix that!

Comment: Now it its working! Thanks alot, can't believe I forgot about the wp_head.. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Please edit the path for the style sheet

And put the code in functions.php

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css',false,'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

Comment: What if you remove the `css` from the path and just try`wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',false,'all' );` within the enqueue hook

Comment: Ya you are right but he told that he has this file in css folder too

Answer (score 1):

try define the css url.

for example this:

wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_css.css')    );

Comment: Still same problem..